# Do you need Xbox Live Gold to play GTA V with Rockstar Social Club?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

When I try to take a selfie in GTA V, or look at some leaderboards of some events, I get a warning that "Xbox Live is not available (or not supported) for your account". The strange thing is, I have an Xbox Live account and I am logged in it, but the game still gives me the warning. Do I need to buy Xbox Live Gold membership to get rid of it, or am I doing something wrong?

P.S. I do have attached my Xbox 360 gamer tag to my Social Club account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use any piece of Xbox Live's uploading service, you must have an Xbox Live Gold Account. It technically falls under the Multiplayer aspect, as far as I know Silver Accounts are only allowed to purchase games over Live's Marketplace, Send Messages, and at one point in time they were allowed to join Parties but I am not sure that this is the case.

**Long Answer Short, Yes.**

> You need Gold for the leaderboards too. Anything that requires the cloud save storage needs a Gold subscription, so that includes Snapmatic pictures and the iFruit app. You can train Chop and order customisations on your iPhone/iPod but unless you have a subscription the game won't load them.

--[tommysalive of GTAForums.com](http://gtaforums.com/topic/592413-xbox-live-gold-reqired-for-social-club-etc/)

Comment: training chop works for me without xbox live gold. snapmatic won't though

Comment: @onnovdw It's someone else's words, I just now that most of the multiplayer aspect won't sync. feel free to edit.

Comment: this is not true.
I don't have a Gold subscription but if I train Chop or "pimp my rides" they are properly delivered in my garage and Chop does all the tricks he learned in iFruit app.