# Do you need Xbox Live to get the special list of cars?

Tags: xbox-network, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

Do you have to have Xbox Live to have a special list of cars on GTA V?

I have signed up for the social club but don't know how to get the special list of cars.

Comment: Which special cars? :0

Comment: In the big garages there is a prompt to press right on the d-pad to access special cars. Currently this only includes the Eleghy RH8 and I believe this is tied to the Social Club so yes, you most likely need Xbox Live Gold. It seems all of the Social Club features (leaderboards, friend stats, photos) require Gold.

Comment: @PeterFinney - You should post that as an answer

Comment: @Robotnik Have done now. Wanted to double check this was the case before posting it properly.

Comment: Closely related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/131605/do-you-need-xbox-live-gold-to-play-gta-v-with-rockstar-social-club/131717#131717

Answer (score 5):

Each character has their own special garage (purchasable, not the one at their houses) when you are in one there should be a prompt to press right on the d-pad to access special cars.

On my normal Xbox Gold account this works fine but on a secondary Xbox Silver account this prompt does not appear at all.

Currently the special car list only includes the Eleghy RH8 which is a Rockstar Social Club bonus car.

On the Xbox 360 version most of the Social Club content (including leaderboards, friend stats and photos) requires Xbox Live Gold so it looks like yes, you will currently require an Xbox Live Gold account to access the Special Cars list.

Comment: But they still can train chop too.

Comment: @ColeBusby Good point, there have been reports of that. Tweaked it to say "most of the Social Club content". Thanks

Answer (score -2):

I FOUND THE PROBLEM!!!!

YOU JUST HAVE TO GO ONLINE MODE AND DO ALL UPDATES AND PATCH YOU CAN DO TO PLAY ONLINE!!!! 
Then just go back single mode and return to your garage. (You'll have messages from Social club again to say new contains in garage, dock, airport etc...) TADAM Car list as T20, Turismo, Zentorro, etc is back.
I play Xbox360.

Thanks.
NsE420